# PropertyExpression is missing

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, expression, expression-trees

I try to write a simple example using Expressions, but have a strange bug: I can't use `PropertyExpression` at compile time. When I write it I get an error and it doesn't compile 
[image]
But in runtime at breakpoint I can write

```
var runtimeBody = (System.Linq.Expressions.PropertyExpression)body2;
```

and it works, and casts as expected. Framework 4.5.1 is selected as target.

Comment: Because it's `internal`.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

`PropertyExpression` is internal

You should cast it to `System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression` instead, as suggested in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ab528f6a-a60e-4af6-bf31-d58e3f373356/resolving-propertyexpressions-and-fieldexpressions-in-a-custom-linq-provider?forum=linqprojectgeneral).